# Creating an initialization file in pari-gp

Tags: c, pari, pari-gp

This question is definitely a stupid question. But, coming from C; I'm having trouble adding header files or "an initialization" file to my pari-gp code. This is to mean; I have a 1hr compile of code to make one vector; and I can use that vector once initialized; but I want to make a file of this vector such that I can access it once it's compiled once.

Here's the code without a header file; which takes about an hour to compile (given the series precision/numerical precision which are set to 100).

```
\p 100
\ps 100
Phi_Inv(w,l,{n=100}) =
{
    my(out = 0);
    for(i=0,n,
        out = w*exp(out)/(exp(l*(n+1-i))+w)
    );
    out;
}




beta_init(n) = {
    beta_taylor = vector(100,i,polcoef(Phi_Inv(w,l,n),i-1,w));
    print(beta_taylor);
}
```

Rather than the brutal assignment of `beta_taylor`; and the caveman like `print(beta_taylor)`, how can I write this to an initialization file I can package with the script. That is; an X mb file with all the coefficients neatly packed together. And if the file is lost, just run the code (which will take an hour) to write the initialization file again.

I mean, how would I properly do `#include test.h` where `test.h` is just a very long list of Taylor series values. So that I can just include this file, and write `beta_taylor[i]` for the i'th function. Such that it's as simple as including variables, like in C. I know I'm missing something simple and it's frustrating--making me feel stupid.

I'm mostly just asking about the syntax to go about and do this. I think I know how; but I imagine it's not the best way.

Any help or suggestions are greatly (And I really mean it, Greatly) appreciated.

To make a long story short; how do I save `beta_taylor` as a file we load when we initialize the program, and if the file is deleted we can save the program again by running the code for an hour?

Regards

Comment: The Phi_Inv(w,1,n) call should be moved out of the vector: it does not depend on i and makes your code 100 times slower than it should be.

Comment: In fact, beta_taylor = Vec(Phi_Inv(w,1,n), 100); would be an even better solution.

Comment: @K.B. Ha, yeah I noticed that right after I posted this. I was repeatedly calculating ```Phi_Inv```. I changed it to ```beta_taylor = Phi_Inv(w,l,n)``` and I just wrote ```beta_taylor``` to a file, and call it as a ```"t_SER"``` type. I avoided the vector stuff, I just handle it as a series instead. Thanks for the comment though! If I didn't notice it that would've helped a lot ^_^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to serialize your vector of numbers to a file and read it back in later?

[`writebin()`](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html-stable/Programming_in_GP__other_specific_functions.html#writebin) to the rescue. Something like

```
beta_init(n) = {
    beta_taylor = vector(100,i,polcoef(Phi_Inv(w,l,n),i-1,w));
    writebin("beta_taylor.dat", beta_taylor);
}
```

Run the function in one `gp` session, and then in another session, `beta_taylor=read("beta_taylor.dat")`.

---

Compiling your code first with `gp2c` before running it to calculate the numbers will speed things up if you're not already doing that, btw. `gp2c-run` makes it easy by compiling a file and starting a new `gp` session with the resulting shared library already loaded. You might also look into if the parallel operations can be used here to speed up the initial computation; reading the documentation for `parvector()` I don't think it can be, though, because of that mysterious `l` variables used in `beta_init()` that I don't see you define anywhere, but you might be able to re-phrase your equation with hardcoded constants or something.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That's exactly what I wanted! I'm planning to compile this, not at that stage yet. The variable ```l``` is a complex number in the right half plane; I need it as a free variable at the moment. But when the time comes (later in the program); we just plug in ```l = log(2)``` (for instance). I'm fairly new to pari-gp; I've only ever really coded C--so this is really helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: quick question. If I just add a ```beta_taylor = read("beta_taylor.dat");``` in the beginning of my file--so long as the file is in the same folder as the source; would this work essentially like an ```#include beta_taylor.dat``` command? Such that I could compile these things as one?

Comment: @RichardDiagram The file would have to exist at runtime. It's not like the C preprocessor's include directive.

Comment: Figured as much; thought I'd ask anyway. Thanks again! Super helpful; already have been able to run trials much faster!

Comment: I've taken the route to load a basic set of GP-routines from an `__init.gp`-file, which is called/included at Pari/GP-start. This can be configured in the GP-initialization file. The path for data- or such initializing files can also be set to be different to your workig file with your GP-sources. If you need this more precise I could show my init-routine.

Answer (score 1):

An initialization for Pari/GP, at program start:
(file `gprc.txt` in directory of `gp.exe`)

---

```
lines  = 25
colors = "brightfg"
histfile = "gp_history.txt"
breakloop = 0
help = "@ perl\\perl gphelp.pl -detex -ch 10 -cb 11 -cu 12"
prompt = "gp >"
prompt_cont="gpc>"
datadir = "u://paritty/syntax/_v11/"
path = "u://paritty/syntax/_v11/"
primelimit = 100 000 000
parisizemax = 1 000 000 000
read  "__init.gp"
echo = 0
```

---

The file `__init.gp` contains my generally used functions; commands to read precomputed data-vectors can of course be included there. If no path is indicated it will be searched in the directory given in the `path=` statement.